# Rails integration test with selenium as webdriver - can't sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, integration-testing

Hi
I have a very simple integration test

```
require 'integration_test_helper'
Capybara.current_driver = :rack_test

class AdminSignsInTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test 'can sign in' do
    email = 'bob@example.com'
    password = 'secret_password'
    Admin.create email: email, password: password

    visit new_admin_session_path
    fill_in 'admin_email', with: email
    fill_in 'admin_password', with: password

    click_button I18n.t('devise.views.sign_in')

    assert_equal I18n.t('devise.sessions.signed_in'), find('p.notice').text
  end
end
```

When I set Capybara driver to `rack_test` test passes, but when I set it to `selenium`, it fails with 'Invalid email or password.' on the login page (I'm using Devise). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See Avdi Grimm's article: [Configuring database_cleaner with Rails, RSpec, Capybara, and Selenium](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> When I set Capybara driver to rack_test test passes, but when I set it to selenium, it fails with 'Invalid email or password.' on the login page (I'm using Devise). What am I doing wrong?

You'll have to check `use_transactional_fixtures`. When using transactional fixtures, because Selenium (or, any of the *external* drivers, which aren't `Rack::Test`) do not have access to information that has been written to the database. (as the transaction hasn't been "Committed")

You can resolve this inside of your `test_helper.rb` with the following:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

You may want, at the same time to look into something like [Database Cleaner](http://rubygems.org/gems/database_cleaner), as without transactional fixtures, your database will become untidy.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot about this question. The problem doesn't exist any more. I spent some time trying to fix it, posted this question and the next day it just worked as it should. Something stupid like forgot to restart spork maybe. Should I try and delete this question? You are right that definitely was because of transactional_fixtures problem. I'm using shared connection hack.

Comment: Unless you've any objection, I'd appreciate the *Accept*, my answer will still help people suffering a similar problem.

Answer (score 9):

From http://opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/:

You will also need DatabaseCleaner, since transactional fixtures do not work with Selenium. Add the database_cleaner gem to the :test group of your Gemfile and put the following code into spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: THANK YOU OMG! setting `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` fixed it so that I could run selenium as well as the normal Rack::Tests. Happily running Rspec/Capybara:Selenium with Device/Warden login now (and not having to use the Devise sign in form but using Warden login_as() helper instead for faster tests. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I found mattwinder's answer worked, but I also had to comment out the line

`config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`

in spec/spec_helper.rb as well.  Just overriding it in spec/support/database_cleaner.rb wasn't sufficient to make logins work with Selenium.